# writing VBA code to call R script

Tags: r, vba, rexcel

I've downloaded and installed Rconn as well as Rexcel. The API appears to be working as I am able to copy my code from R into Excel and then, through the use of the API GUI I am able to extract values for one of my matrices.

The problem I'm having is within VBA. When I try and run the following line: 
`RInterface.StartRServer`
I get the following error message: "Run-time error'424': Object required"

Would anyone be able to help me understand why I'm getting this error? Am I perhaps meant to load something from "Tools/References"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it out. It was a reference problem. Once the rconn and RExcel are install you have to go to tools>References>RExcelVBAlib.

This will then allow you to use RExcel within VBA