# How to keep a shell window open for the lifespan of a workbook

Tags: r, vba, shell, excel

I can call a script in R from VBA by doing

```
Sub CallRScript()
    Dim myShell As Object
    Set myShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean, style As Integer, path As String
    waitTillComplete = True
    style = 1
    path = "RScript C:\R_code\Scripts\ValuationFns.R"

    Call myShell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

However, the R session closes as soon as the R script is finished running.  I'd like for the R session to remain open until the excel workbook is closed, an be able to run subsequent commands in the command prompt.  How might I accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091746/writing-vba-code-to-call-r-script

Comment: http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMServer/  (Notice that I am offering non-RScript approaches since as far as I know RScript will automatically close after completion of a task. Other approaches are offered by Dirk's `littler`.)